# retrieve data from database into textboxes using jsf and to edit that data

Tags: java, jsf

I do not know how to edit the data which is brought from database using jsf.could you please help me by providing examples and i would be very grateful to you..
Thank you.

Comment: what have you done so far ? where do you stuck at ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the source code but steps you can follow:

1. display data in textboxes.
2. make an update button.
3. onclick of update button do following:

   3.1 get values from textboxes.

   3.2 connect to database.

   3.3 create an update query and run that query.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JSF_Tutorial) should get you started. It uses [EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink) to access the database.